# Edit existing excel files ASP.Net without losing formatting

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, closedxml

I have a situation where I need to use an Excel Template and insert values, then allow the user to download the updated file. I have done this using ClosedXML but as it uses a non native format for xlsx, I get a format error when opening the downloaded document and the saved instance of the document looses all formatting from the template.

I need a solution that outputs a xlsx document that is a copy of the original template, formatting and all, with the additional inserted values. If necessary, I can make a temporary copy of the template on the server.

Is there a tool I can use for this purpose?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Comment: ClosedXML will work, but you need to give a much more detailed question if you want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using OpenXML. I am using VB.Net for this project and as I found very little example code in VB (mostly java or c#), I will attach it so it can be used as a reference.

The really nice thing about it is the document you get out of it does not have any validation errors or anything and all sheet formatting (text justification, font face, etc) survives.

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim path = Server.MapPath("~/ExcelTemplates/rfi.xlsx")

    Dim templateBytes As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)
    Using templateStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream

        templateStream.Write(templateBytes, 0, templateBytes.Length)

        Using sheetInstance As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(templateStream, True)

            Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = GetWorksheetPartByName(sheetInstance, "Sheet1")

            If worksheetPart IsNot Nothing Then

                'this writes "Test!!!" to cell C7
                'Dim cell As Cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, "C", 7)
                'cell.CellValue = New CellValue("Test!!!")

                'another way of doing it
                GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, "C", 7).CellValue = New CellValue("Test12")

                'this next line would change the cell's contents data type
                'cell.DataType = New EnumValue(Of CellValues)(CellValues.String)

                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save()
                templateStream.Position = 0

                Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream

                    templateStream.CopyTo(ms)
                    Response.Buffer = True
                    Response.Clear()
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=RFI.xlsx")
                    ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
                    Response.End()

                End Using

            End If


        End Using


    End Using

End Sub

Private Shared Function GetWorksheetPartByName(ByVal document As SpreadsheetDocument, ByVal sheetName As String) As WorksheetPart
    Dim sheets As IEnumerable(Of Sheet) = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild(Of Sheets)().Elements(Of Sheet)().Where(Function(s) s.Name = sheetName)

    If sheets.Count() = 0 Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim relationshipId As String = sheets.First().Id.Value
    Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = CType(document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId), WorksheetPart)
    Return worksheetPart
End Function

Private Shared Function GetCell(ByVal worksheet As Worksheet, ByVal columnName As String, ByVal rowIndex As UInteger) As Cell
    Dim row As Row = GetRow(worksheet, rowIndex)
    If row Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Return row.Elements(Of Cell)().Where(Function(c) String.Compare(c.CellReference.Value, columnName & rowIndex, True) = 0).First()
End Function

Private Shared Function GetRow(ByVal worksheet As Worksheet, ByVal rowIndex As UInteger) As Row
    Return worksheet.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)().Elements(Of Row)().Where(Function(r) CType(r.RowIndex, UInteger) = rowIndex).First()
End Function
```